# Cannot instantiate interface Magento\MediaGalleryApi\Model\Asset\Command\GetByPathInterface Magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3, magento2.4

I have upgraded Magento version from **2.3.5-p2** to **2.4.3**

After upgraded to 2.4.3 version, i have cleared all the cache and generated folder. Then I ran the upgrade command then i got the below error:

```
Cannot instantiate interface Magento\MediaGalleryApi\Model\Asset\Command\GetByPathInterface#0 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#1 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#2 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument()
#3 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument()
#4 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#5 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments()
#6 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#7 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#8 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument()
#9 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument()
#10 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#11 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments()
#12 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#13 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#14 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument()
#15 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument()
#16 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#17 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments()
#18 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#19 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(206): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#20 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(182): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->parseArray()
#21 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument()
#22 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument()
#23 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#24 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments()
#25 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#26 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#27 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument()
#28 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument()
#29 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#30 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments()
#31 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#32 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#33 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument()
#34 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument()
#35 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#36 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments()
#37 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#38 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(206): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#39 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(182): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->parseArray()
#40 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument()
#41 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument()
#42 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#43 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments()
#44 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#45 /vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(153): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create()
#46 /vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(134): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getApplicationCommands()
#47 /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1274): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getDefaultCommands()
#48 /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(629): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->init()
#49 /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(237): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find()
#50 /vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#51 /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun()
#52 /bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#53 {main}
```

I tried to fix by flushing cache but didn't work. if anyone have any idea, please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: check php version and composer version

Comment: Composer version 2.3.5 & PHP 7.4.29

Comment: remove generated/redis cache

Comment: I did that but still not working. Getting same error.

Answer (score 2):

Check the status of Magento_MediaGallery in app/etc/config.php

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing some files in your vendor folder. To recreate the vendor folder, we need to reinstall composer.

remove vendor folder command-

```
rm -rf vendor/*
```

clear composer cache command

```
composer clearcache
```

composer install command

```
composer install
```

After that run the basic command of Magento (setup upgrade, deploy, compile, reindex, cache flush)

Comment: This is the best solution imho

Comment: I tried this also but didn't work

Comment: You are getting the same error or error changed.

Comment: Getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by disabling and removing Magento_MediaGalleryApi module first and then reinstall it.
then run upgrade and deploy command.

You can remove module using composer.json file using replace.

please follow this link to remove module using composer.js

https://www.integer-net.com/blog_english/removing-unused-core-modules-from-magento-2-the-right-way